# plt.imshow is not working as it should be

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

so i have this code in python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = np.zeros((490,1900))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(M, aspect='auto')
ax.set_ylabel('f2')
ax.set_xlabel('f1')
plt.xlim((0, 490))
plt.ylim((0, 1900))
x_range = np.arange(0, 490, step=50)
x_strings = [str(x+190) for x in x_range]
plt.xticks(x_range, x_strings)
y_range = np.arange(0, 1900, step=200)
y_strings = [str(y+1710) for y in y_range]
plt.yticks(y_range, y_strings)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

when i'm compiling it supposed to cover the whole area with the grid of zeros (M) that I've created, but instead it covers part of it as seen in this

[image: picture]

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you have rows and cols flipped. 490 rows and 1900 cols. so xlims should be 0 to 1900 and y lims from 0 to 490

Answer (score 1):

I think you're simply confusing yourself when creating the matrix.

You're creating a matrix with 490 rows and 1900 columns when you're probably aiming to create a matrix with 1900 rows and 490 columns.

Your problem can be solved simply by changing the order with which you define your matrix `M`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = np.zeros((1900, 490)) # change is here
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(M, aspect='auto')
ax.set_ylabel('f2')
ax.set_xlabel('f1')
plt.xlim((0, 490))
plt.ylim((0, 1900))
x_range = np.arange(0, 490, step=50)
x_strings = [str(x+190) for x in x_range]
plt.xticks(x_range, x_strings)
y_range = np.arange(0, 1900, step=200)
y_strings = [str(y+1710) for y in y_range]
plt.yticks(y_range, y_strings)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Which yields:

[image]

---

You could of course also be changing the plot limits by inverting `xlim` and `ylim`.